# Show that $n^4-6n^3+11n^2-6n$ is divisible by $4$ for every integer $n$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

So I am trying to refresh my memory when it comes to modular arithmetic but I am having some difficulties. The problem as states in the title is:

> Show that $n^{4}-6n^{3}+11n^{2}-6n$ is divisible by $4$ för every
>   integer $n$.

So what I first did was reformulating the problem in terms of congruences, in the following way:

$$4\vert (n^{4}-6n^{3}+11n^{2}-6n) \iff  4\vert (n^{4}+11n^{2}-(6n^{3}+6n))\\ \hspace{6cm} \iff  n^{4}+11n^{2}\equiv 6n^{3}+6n\pmod 4$$

Now, one initial question I have is if it is correct that the only cases I need to check is:

$$n^{4}+11n^{2}\equiv 0\equiv 6n^{3}+6n\pmod 4 \\ n^{4}+11n^{2}\equiv 1\equiv 6n^{3}+6n\pmod 4\\ n^{4}+11n^{2}\equiv 2\equiv 6n^{3}+6n\pmod 4\\n^{4}+11n^{2}\equiv 3\equiv 6n^{3}+6n\pmod 4,$$

since $0,1,2,3$ are the possible remainders when considering division by $4$?

If this is true, it still seams like a really tedious approach to solving the problem. So I am wondering if there is some other way of solving it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104201/prove-for-all-n-geq-0-that-3-mid-n36n211n6).

Comment: $n^{4}-6n^{3}+11n^{2}-6n=24\cdot \binom{n}{4}$

Comment: Don't bother checking of the *outcomes* are equivalent to 0,1,2,3 and solve.  Check if the *input* of $n$ is equivalent to $0,1,2,3$ and check if the outcomes $0^4 + 11*0^2 \equiv 6*0^3 + 6*0; 1^4 + 11*1^2 = 6*1^3 + 6*1; 2^4+11*2^2 \equiv 6*2^3 + 6*2; 3^4 + 11*3^3 \equiv 6*3^3 + 6*3$.

Answer (score 9):

Hint: Use that $$n^4-6n^3+11n^2-6n=(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n$$

Comment: Okay. Now I think I see the solution! $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)=\dfrac{n!}{(n-4)!}=4!\cdot {n \choose 4}$ which is divisible by $4$ since the factor $4!$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: @VictorGaleano It's simpler to do a parity argument, i.e. consider the cases $n$ even and $n$ odd - which requires no factorizatio - see my answer. For much larger problems factorization would be very difficult but the parity argument still remains very simple.

Comment: Distinguish the cases $$n \equiv 0,1,2,3\mod 4$$ then it is easy.

Comment: @Dr.S  Yes, such a case analysis also requires no factorization, which is essentially the same as what I posted (I used partiy since that points the way to generalizations).

Comment: Alternatively, note that one of the four factors $n, n-1, n-2, n-3$ must be divisible by 4.

Comment: That is surely the best and the shortest way!

Comment: @MichaelLugo The point is to *avoid* factorization if possible (since it is generally very expensive) Above is really cheating since the factorization is pulled out of a hat - like magic. But magic is not math.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I can see how  the parity argument can be used to show that it is divisible by 4. How can one directly see that one of the factors n, n-1,n-2 or n-3 is divisible by 4?

Comment: Note that four consecutive numbers are always divisible by four.

Comment: "The point is to avoid factorization if possible" I both agree and disagree. I think the insight that "every set of $k$ consecutive numbers contains one that is divisible by $k$ so $n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k-1)\equiv 0 \pmod k$" is invaluable an something every student should learn. But factoring is ...hard. I'd reduce and do partial factoring $n^4 -6n^3+11n^2 -6n=n^4-n^2 -2n^3-2n=n^2(n+1)(n-1) - 2n(n^2+1)$ would make check the congruences for $n\equiv 0,1,2,3$ *very* easy. $n^2\equiv 2n\equiv 0$ if $n\equiv 0,2$ while $(n+1)(n-1)\equiv 0$ if $n\equiv 1,3$ while $n^2+1\equiv 2$ so $2(n^2+1)\equiv 0$.

Comment: If you have $k$ consecutive numbers than one of them must be divisible by $k$.   Every possible remainder will be represented  once-- including $0$.  If $n$ is the first number and $k\not \mid n$ then then $n=kq+r$ where $0 < r < k$.  So then the number $n + (k-r)$ will be equal to $n + (k-r) = kq+r +(k-r) = kq+k = k(q+1)$ is divisible by $k$.  And as your numbers are $n, n+1, ....., n+(k-1)$ the number $n+(k-r)$ is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

$2\mid n\Rightarrow 4\mid n^2\,$ so $\!\bmod 4\!:\, f_n\equiv\overbrace{ -6n\equiv 0;}^{\large -12n(n/2)}\,$ else $n$ odd so $\,\color{#c00}{n^2\equiv 1}\,$ so $\,f_n\equiv\overbrace{1-6n+11-6n}^{\large \color{#c00}{n^4} -\,6\color{#c00}{n^3}+11\color{#c00}{n^2}-6n\ }\equiv 0$

Comment: In case it's not clear: $\ n^2\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, n^3\equiv n\,\Rightarrow\, n^4\equiv 1.\,$ We could also simply check all cases $\, n\equiv 0,1,2,3\pmod{4},\,$ but the parity argument points the way towards generalizations (e.g. Hensel lifting and related ideas).

Answer (score 1):

Continuing your idea (which isn't quite what I would have done) you can reduce the coefficients.

$n^{4}-6n^{3}+11n^{2}-6n \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \iff$

$n^4 + 11n^2 \equiv 6n^3 + 6n \pmod 4\iff$

$n^4 - n^2 \equiv 2n^3 + 2n\pmod 4\iff$

$n^2(n-1)(n+1) \equiv 2n(n^2 + 1)\mod 4\iff$

The check if $n\equiv 0\pmod 4$ then LHS and RHS are both $\equiv 0\pmod 4$.

If $n\equiv 3\equiv -1 \pmod 4$ or $n \equiv 1\pmod 4$ then $n\equiv \pm 1\pmod 4$ and $n\mp 1 \equiv 0\pmod 4$ so LHS is $\equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  And $n^2 +1\equiv 2\pmod 4$ an $2n \equiv \pm 2$ so RHS is $\equiv \pm 4 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

And if $n \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ then $n^2 \equiv 4 \equiv 0\pmod 4$ so LHS $\equiv 0\pmod 4$. meanwhile $2n\equiv 4\equiv 0 \pmod 4$. So RHS $\equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

So in all cases: $n^2(n+1)(n-1) \equiv 2n(n^2+1)\equiv 0\pmod 4$.

......

But I wouldn't have done it that way.

Perhaps the must informative, but most needlessly calculating way would be to factor.

$n^4 -6n^2 + 11n^2 -6n = n(n^3 - 6n^2 + 11n -6)=$

$n(n-1)(n^2 -5n^2 + 6)=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$

Note: $n-3, n-2,n-1, n$ are four consecutive numbers!  So *ONE* of them is divisible by $4$.  So the product must be divisible by $4$.

That is an important lesson!  And an important strategy to learn.

But ... factoring is hard.

.......

If I were to do it my way, I'd reduce

$n^4 -6n^3 +11n^2 -6n \equiv n^4 + 2n^3 -n^2+2n\pmod 4$.

For $n\equiv 0,1,2,-1\pmod n$ we have $n^2 \equiv0,1,0,1\pmod n$ and $n^3\equiv 0,1,0,-1\pmod n$ and $n^4 \equiv 0,1,0,1\equiv n^2$ we'd have

$2n \equiv 0,2,0,-2\equiv 0,2,0,2$ and $2n^3 \equiv 0,2,0,2\equiv 2n$

So we have $n^4 + 2n^3 - n^2 + 2n \equiv n^2 +2n - n^2+ 2n\equiv 4n\equiv 0*n\equiv 0\pmod 4$.

.....

Which hints at Bill Dubuque's parity argument.

If $n$ is even than $n^4, n^3, n^2, 6n$ are all divisible by $4$.

If $n$ is odd then $n\equiv \pm 1$ and $n^4-6n^3 + 11n^2 -6n\equiv 1\mp 6+11 \mp 6=12 \mp 12\equiv 0\mp 0 \equiv 0\pmod 4$

Comment: thanks for the answer. How does one show that in a sequence of four consecutive numbers, one number will always be divisible by 4?

Comment: Oh I know! Two of the factors has to be even, say $2k$ and $2l$, so one can factor out $4$. Thus the entire product is divisible by $4$. Right?

Comment: It's much simpler than that!  If you list then integers $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,....$ and then list the remainders after dividing by $4$ you get $0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,......$.  If you take any four consecutive numbers, you will have four consecutive remainders.  So if your numbers are $\{n-3, n-2,n-1,n\}$ the congruences will by $\{0,1,2,3\}$.  The only thing is you don't know which one starts with which.  BUt *one* of them will be $\equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  And another will by $\equiv 1$ and another $\equiv 2$ and the last will be $\equiv 3\pmod 4$.

Comment: If you have $k$ consecutive numbers exactly one will by divisible by $k$ and exactly one will have remainder $1$ and exactly one will have remainder $2$ and so on.

Comment: oh! Yeah, that's true! Nice.